# Using array values as hash keys to create nested hashes in Ruby

Tags: ruby

## Background

I have a directory of files.  The majority of them are `.patch` files, although some of them are not.  For each patch file, I need to scan the first line which is always a string and extract a portion of that line.  With a combination of each file's name, that portion of each first line, and a unique identifier for each file, I need to create a hash which I will then convert to json and write to a file.

Here are examples:

### Directory of Files (Example)

```
|__ .gitkeep
|__ pmet-add-install-module-timings.patch
|__ pmet-change-sample-data-load-order.patch
|__ pmet-stop-catching-sample-data-errrors-during-install.patch
|__ pmet-fix-admin-label-word-breaking.patch
|__ pmet-declare-shipping-factory-for-compilation.patch.disabled

...
```

### First Line Examples

*File Name:* `pmet-add-install-module-timings.patch`

*First Line:* `diff --git a/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/Installer.php b/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/Installer.php`

*File Name:* `pmet-change-sample-data-load-order.patch`

*First Line:* `diff --git a/vendor/magento/module-sample-data/etc/module.xml b/vendor/magento/module-sample-data/etc/module.xml`

*File Name:* `pmet-stop-catching-sample-data-errrors-during-install.patch`

*First Line:* `diff --git a/vendor/magento/framework/Setup/SampleData/Executor.php b/vendor/magento/framework/Setup/SampleData/Executor.php`

*File Name:* `pmet-fix-admin-label-word-breaking.patch`

*First Line:* `diff --git a/vendor/magento/theme-adminhtml-backend/web/css/styles-old.less b/vendor/magento/theme-adminhtml-backend/web/css/styles-old.less`

### JSON File Example

```
{
    "patches": {
        "magento/magento2-base": {
            "Patch 1": "m2-hotfixes/pmet-add-install-module-timings.patch"
        },
        "magento/module-sample-data": {
            "Patch 2": "m2-hotfixes/pmet-change-sample-data-load-order.patch"
        },
        "magento/theme-adminhtml-backend": {
            "Patch 3": "m2-hotfixes/pmet-fix-admin-label-word-breaking.patch"
        },
        "magento/framework": {
            "Patch 4": "m2-hotfixes/pmet-stop-catching-sample-data-errrors-during-install.patch"
        }
    }
}
```

### The Solution So Far `scrape.rb`

Here's the code in its entirety.  I will break it down further below:

```rb
files_hash = Hash.new
modules = Array.new
data_hash = {
    patches: {}
}
files = Dir["*.patch"]
files.each do |file|
    files_hash.store(files.index(file), file)
end
files_hash.each do |key, file|
    value = File.open(file, &:readline).split('/')[3]
    if value.match(/module-/) || value.match(/theme-/)
        result = "magento/#{value}"
    else
        result = "magento2-base"
    end
    modules << result
    modules.each do |val|
        data_hash[:patches][val][key] = "m2-hotfixes/#{file}"
    end
end
print data_hash
```

Before I highlight the problem, I need to first detail what I've done to achieve the desired end result:

First, I set up an empty files hash, module array, and data hash:

```rb
files_hash = Hash.new
modules = Array.new
data_hash = {
    patches: {}
}
```

Next, I scan the patch file directory for `.patch` files and store them in the files hash with their keys.  (I figure I can use the keys as the patch labels in the JSON file):

```rb
files = Dir["*.patch"]
files.each do |file|
    files_hash.store(files.index(file), file)
end
```

Next, I use the file hash to read the first line of each patch file.  I notice a pattern in the patch files which I believe will be reliable: each file has either `magento/module-name`, `magento/theme-name` or something else. Both the `module-name` and `theme-name` cases will use the `magento/#{value}` syntax.  The "something else" case will use `magento/magento2-base`:

```rb
files_hash.each do |key, file|
    value = File.open(file, &:readline).split('/')[3]
    if value.match(/module-/) || value.match(/theme-/)
        result = "magento/#{value}"
    else
        result = "magento2-base"
    end
    modules << result
...
```

This isn't the *most ideal* solution (what if the diff structure changes?) but it works for now, and I couldn't quite figure out the proper regex to use to search the strings and return the same result.  The above code gives me what I want, which is the following array:

```rb
#=>["magento2-base", "magento/module-sample-data", "magento/theme-adminhtml-backend", "magento2-base"]
```

Next, while still able to access the file names and keys from the file hash, I need to loop through this array and create hashes which have the array values as a key and the file names as values (appended to a file path).  Like so, (or so I thought):

```rb
    modules.each do |val|
        data_hash[:patches][val][key] = "m2-hotfixes/#{file}"
    end
end
```

It's this part of the code which I'm having issues with. Running this gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    4: from scrape.rb:10:in `<main>'
    3: from scrape.rb:10:in `each'
    2: from scrape.rb:18:in `block in <main>'
    1: from scrape.rb:18:in `each'
scrape.rb:19:in `block (2 levels) in <main>': undefined method `[]=' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

I notice that if I omit `key` like so: `data_hash` to `data_hash[:patches][val]`, I get a hash of values.

So then, my obvious question:

Why doesn't my approach of nesting the hashes one level further using keys work above?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer I've come up with:

```rb
require 'json'

files_hash = Hash.new
file_hash = Hash.new
result_hash = Hash.new
data_hash = Hash.new
remap_hash = Hash.new 
final_hash = {"patches" => {}}
files = Dir["*.patch"]
patches_file = File.dirname(File.expand_path(__FILE__)) + "/patches.json"

files.each do |file|
    files_hash.store(files.index(file), file)
end
files_hash.each do |key, file|
    value = File.open(file, &:readline).split('/')[3]
    if value.match(/module-/) || value.match(/theme-/)
        result = "magento/#{value}"
    else
        result = "magento2-base"
    end
    data_hash[key] = result
    file_hash[key] = "m2-hotfixes/#{file}"
end

data_hash.each do |data_key, data_vals|
    file_hash.each do |file_key, file_vals|
        if data_key == file_key
            remap_hash[data_vals] = {
                "Patch #{data_key}" => file_vals
            }
        end
    end
end

final_hash["patches"].merge!(remap_hash)

File.open(patches_file, "w+") do |file|
    file.puts(final_hash.to_json)
end
```

This yields the following: `patches.json` **NB:** I used a different patches file set than above, the key is the formatting here:

```
{
    "patches": {
        "magento2-base": {
            "Patch 6": "m2-hotfixes/pmet-fix-module-loader-algorithm.patch"
        },
        "magento/module-downloadable-sample-data": {
            "Patch 2": "m2-hotfixes/pmet-fix-sample-data-code-generator.patch"
        },
        "magento/module-customer": {
            "Patch 3": "m2-hotfixes/pmet-visitor-segment.patch"
        }
    }
}
```

Some pros and cons:

### Pros

It works. Awesome.

### Cons

1. I know it can be more elegant
2. One unforeseen need I have run into is the fact that my `patches.json` file may have duplicate patches which need to be applied to the same file. Something like:

```
{
    "patches": {
        "magento2-base": {
            "Patch 1": "m2-hotfixes/pmet-add-install-module-timings.patch"
            "Patch 6": "m2-hotfixes/pmet-fix-module-loader-algorithm.patch"
        },
        "magento/module-downloadable-sample-data": {
            "Patch 2": "m2-hotfixes/pmet-fix-sample-data-code-generator.patch"
        },
        "magento/module-customer": {
            "Patch 3": "m2-hotfixes/pmet-visitor-segment.patch"
        }
    }
}
```

My solution needs to account for this, since Ruby doesn't allow for duplicate keys in hashes.

I would welcome a more elegant solution to the challenge that considered this quirk.