# How to stitch together two arrays based on a common set of keys in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I have two arrays of hashes which are related by a common set of keys:

Array 1 is:

```
[
  {0=>"pmet-add-install-module-timings.patch"},
  {1=>"pmet-change-sample-data-load-order.patch"},
  {2=>"pmet-configurable-recurring.patch"},
  {3=>"pmet-consumers-run-staggered-by-sleep.patch"},
  {4=>"pmet-dynamic-block-segment-display.patch"},
  {5=>"pmet-fix-admin-label-word-breaking.patch"},
  {6=>"pmet-fix-invalid-module-dependencies.patch"},
  {7=>"pmet-fix-invalid-sample-data-module-dependencies.patch"},
  {8=>"pmet-fix-module-loader-algorithm.patch"},
  {9=>"pmet-fix-sample-data-code-generator.patch"},
  {10=>"pmet-remove-id-requirement-from-layout-update-file.patch"},
  {11=>"pmet-specify-store-id-for-order.patch"},
  {12=>"pmet-staging-preview-js-fix.patch"},
  {13=>"pmet-stop-catching-sample-data-errrors-during-install.patch"},
  {14=>"pmet-visitor-segment.patch"}
]
```

Array 2 is:

```
[
  {0=>"magento2-base"},
  {1=>"magento/module-sample-data"},
  {2=>"magento/module-configurable-sample-data"},
  {3=>"magento/module-message-queue"},
  {4=>"magento/module-banner"},
  {5=>"magento/theme-adminhtml-backend"},
  {6=>"magento/module-staging"},
  {7=>"magento/module-gift-registry-sample-data"},
  {8=>"magento2-base"},
  {9=>"magento/module-downloadable-sample-data"},
  {10=>"magento/module-catalog"},
  {11=>"magento/module-sales-sample-data"},
  {12=>"magento/module-staging"},
  {13=>"magento2-base"},
  {14=>"magento/module-customer"}
]
```

The hashes in these arrays have the same set of indexes, and the second array has duplicate values in keys `0`, `8`, and `13` as well as in `6` and `12`.

My goal is to stitch the values from these two data sets together into a set of nested hashes.  Wherever there is a duplicated value in Array 2, I need to collect its associated values from Array 1 and include them in a nested hash.

For example, take the `magento2-base` values from Array 2 and the key-associated values from Array 1.  The hash structure in Ruby would look like:

```
hash = {
  "magento2-base" => [
    {0 => "m2-hotfixes/pmet-add-install-module-timings.patch"},
    {8 => "m2-hotfixes/pmet-fix-module-loader-algorithm.patch"},
    {13 => "m2-hotfixes/pmet-stop-catching-sample-data-errrors-during-install.patch"}
  ]
}
```

The same would hold true for any other duplicated values from Array 2, so, for example, `magento/module-staging` would be:

```
hash = {
  "magento/module-staging" => [
    {6 => "pmet-fix-invalid-module-dependencies.patch"},
    {12 => "pmet-staging-preview-js-fix.patch"}
  ]
}
```

A larger excerpt of the resultant hash which combines these needs together would look like this:

```
hash = {
  "magento2-base" => 
  [
    {0 => "m2-hotfixes/pmet-add-install-module-timings.patch"},
    {8 => "m2-hotfixes/pmet-fix-module-loader-algorithm.patch"},
    {13 => "m2-hotfixes/pmet-stop-catching-sample-data-errrors-during-install.patch"}
  ],
  "magento/module-sample-data" => 
  {0 => "pmet-change-sample-data-load-order.patch"},
    "magento/module-configurable-sample-data" =>
  {2 => "pmet-configurable-recurring.patch"},
    "magento/module-message-queue" =>
  {3 => "pmet-consumers-run-staggered-by-sleep.patch"}
  "magento/module-staging" => 
  [
    {6 => "pmet-fix-invalid-module-dependencies.patch"},
    {12 => "pmet-staging-preview-js-fix.patch"}
  ],
    ...
}
```

I used a nested loop which combines both arrays to link up the keys, and attempted to pull out the duplicates from Array 2, and was thinking I'd need to maintain both an array of the duplicate values from array 2 as well as an array of their associated values from Array 1. Then, I'd use some array merging magic to put it all back together.

Here's what I have:

```
found_modules_array = []
duplicate_modules_array = []
duplicate_module_hash = {}
file_collection_array = []

modules_array.each do |module_hash|
  module_hash.each do |module_hash_key, module_hash_value|
    files_array.each do |file_hash|
      file_hash.each do |file_hash_key, file_hash_value|
        if module_hash_key == file_hash_key
          if found_modules_array.include?(module_hash_value)
            duplicate_module_hash = {
              module_hash_key => module_hash_value
            }
            duplicate_modules_array << duplicate_module_hash
          end
          found_modules_array << module_hash_value
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

In this code, `files_array` is Array 1 and `modules_array` is Array 2. `found_modules_array` is a bucket to hold any duplicates before pushing them into a `duplicate_module_hash` which would then be pushed into the `duplicates_modules_array`.

This solution:

1. Doesn't work
2. Doesn't take advantage of the power of Ruby
3. Isn't performant

---

### EDIT

The path to the above data structure is explained in full detail in the following post: [Using array values as hash keys to create nested hashes in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60785535/using-array-values-as-hash-keys-to-create-nested-hashes-in-ruby)

I'll summarize it below:

I have a directory of files.  The majority of them are `.patch` files, although some of them are not.  For each patch file, I need to scan the first line which is always a string and extract a portion of that line.  With a combination of each file's name, that portion of each first line, and a unique identifier for each file, I need to create a hash which I will then convert to json and write to a file.

Here are examples:

Directory of Files:

```
|__ .gitkeep
|__ pmet-add-install-module-timings.patch
|__ pmet-change-sample-data-load-order.patch
```

First Line Examples:

```
File Name: `pmet-add-install-module-timings.patch`
First Line: `diff --git a/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/Installer.php b/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/Installer.php`

File Name: `pmet-change-sample-data-load-order.patch`
First Line: `diff --git a/vendor/magento/module-sample-data/etc/module.xml b/vendor/magento/module-sample-data/etc/module.xml`

File Name: `pmet-stop-catching-sample-data-errrors-during-install.patch`
First Line: `diff --git a/vendor/magento/framework/Setup/SampleData/Executor.php b/vendor/magento/framework/Setup/SampleData/Executor.php`

File Name: `pmet-fix-admin-label-word-breaking.patch`
First Line: `diff --git a/vendor/magento/theme-adminhtml-backend/web/css/styles-old.less b/vendor/magento/theme-adminhtml-backend/web/css/styles-old.less`
```

Example Json File:

```
{
    "patches": {
        "magento/magento2-base": {
            "Patch 1": "m2-hotfixes/pmet-add-install-module-timings.patch"
        },
        "magento/module-sample-data": {
            "Patch 2": "m2-hotfixes/pmet-change-sample-data-load-order.patch"
        },
        "magento/theme-adminhtml-backend": {
            "Patch 3": "m2-hotfixes/pmet-fix-admin-label-word-breaking.patch"
        },
        "magento/framework": {
            "Patch 4": "m2-hotfixes/pmet-stop-catching-sample-data-errrors-during-install.patch"
        }
    }
}
```

The problem I encountered is that while json allows for duplicate keys, ruby hashes don't, so items were removed from the json file because they were removed from the hash.  To solve this, I assumed I needed to create the array structure I specified so as to keep the IDs as the consistent identifier between the files scraped and the corresponding data belonging to them so that I could put the data together in a different arrangement.  Now I realize this isn't the case, so I have switched the approach to use the following:

```rb
files.each_with_index do |file, key|
    value = File.open(file, &:readline).split('/')[3]
    if value.match(/module-/) || value.match(/theme-/)
        result = "magento/#{value}"
    else
        result = "magento2-base"
    end
    file_array << file
    module_array << result
end
```

This yields the flat hashes that have been suggested below.

---

Comment: Hashes contains only one key-value pair and there are no duplicated indexes. Did you tried to flatten array of hashes into one hash first?

Comment: When asking, please reduce your data and code to the bare minimum necessary to demonstrate the problem. Anything else just wastes everyone's time as we try to help you. "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)"

Comment: This is a very strange data structure. As was already mentioned elsewhere, as a first step, you can flatten the structure so that it is just a `Hash` instead of an `Array` of `Hash`es. But then, a `Hash` with consecutive `Integer` keys starting at `0` is isomorphic to an `Array`. So, why not just use an `Array`? Like `%w[pmet-add-install-module-timings.patch pmet-change-sample-data-load-order.patch pmet-configurable-recurring.patch pmet-consumers-run-staggered-by-sleep.patch pmet-dynamic-block-segment-display.patch pmet-fix-admin-label-word-breaking.patch … ]`

Comment: @the Tin Man thanks for reminder! In my experience on SO, I’ve been yelled at for providing too little context. Since readability is somewhat subjective, it can be difficult to achieve a balance. I appreciate your effort to make my question better. A question for you: In one of the comments to Max, I reference the origin of the strange data structure. I was thinking it might be a good idea to edit the original post to include relevant portions of that. What are your thoughts? Would this help or harm? If help, where would you recommend injecting it in the original?

Comment: As others mentioned, an array of single key/value pair hashes, is weird. It doesn't use the data well. To us it looks like an  XY Problem. See "[What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/153968)"
and "[XyProblem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem)". Explaining and showing that process might allow us to suggest a much more straightforward path. Code should flow and data should go along with it; When the data has to be heavily massaged it's usually a sign that something wasn't done right initially.

Comment: A solution that "doesn't work" usually "isn't performant". :-)

Comment: True!  I only meant to admit that even if I did get it to work using my hacky logic, I knew the result wouldn't be as performant as it could have been.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let `arr1` and `arr2` be your two arrays. Due to the fact that they are the same size and that for each index `i`, `arr1[i][i]` and `arr2[i][i]` are the values of the key `i` of the hashes `arr1[i]` and `arr2[i]`, the desired result can be obtained quite easily:

```
arr2.each_with_index.with_object({}) do |(g,i),h|
  (h[g[i]] ||= []) << arr1[i][i]
end
  #=> {
  #    "magento2-base"=>[
  #    "pmet-add-install-module-timings.patch",
  #    "pmet-fix-module-loader-algorithm.patch",
  #    "pmet-stop-catching-sample-data-errrors-during-install.patch"
  #    ],
  #    "magento/module-sample-data"=>[
  #      "pmet-change-sample-data-load-order.patch"
  #    ],
  #    ...
  #    "magento/module-staging"=>[
  #      "pmet-fix-invalid-module-dependencies.patch",
  #      "pmet-staging-preview-js-fix.patch"
  #    ],
  #    "magento/module-customer"=>[
  #      "pmet-visitor-segment.patch"
  #    ]
  #   }
```

The fragment

```
h[g[i]] ||= []
```

is effectively expanded to

```
h[g[i]] = h[g[i]] || []  # *
```

If the hash `h` has no key `[g[i]]`,

```
h[g[i]] #=> nil
```

so * becomes

```
h[g[i]] = nil || [] #=> []
```

after which

```
h[g[i]] << "cat"
  #=> ["cat"]
```

(which works with `"dog"` as well). The above expression can instead be written:

```
arr2.each_with_index.with_object(Hash.new {|h,k| h[k]=[]}) do |(g,i),h|
  h[g[i]] << arr1[i][i]
end
```

This uses the form of [Hash::new](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-c-new) that employs a block (here `{|h,k| h[k]=[]}`) that is called when the hash is accessed by a value that is not one of its keys.

An alternative method is:

```
arr2.each_with_index.with_object({}) do |(g,i),h|
  h.update(g[i]=>[arr1[i][i]]) { |_,o,n| o+n }
end
```

This uses the form of [Hash#update](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) (aka `merge!`) that employs a block to determine the values of keys that are in both hashes being merged.

A third way is to use [Enumerable#group_by](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by):

```
arr2.each_with_index.group_by { |h,i| arr2[i][i] }.
     transform_values { |a| a.map { |_,i| arr1[i][i] } }
```

Comment: Hi Cary!  Really intrigued by this and I really like the use of each_with_object.  Am I correct in understanding that by "Let arr1 and arr2 be your two arrays" you mean the arrays of hashes I originally specified and NOT the flattened hashes that others have suggested?

Comment: The arrays you call "Array 1" and "Array 2". When giving examples it is helpful to attach a variable to each input (e.g., `arr1 = [{0=>"pmet-add-install-module-timings.patch"},..]`.) That simplifies cutting and pasting but mainly it allows readers to refer to those variables in comments and answers without having to define them. Also, everyone will then use the same variables in their answers.

Comment: Unfortunately, I think the data structure I used is one of the key reasons for my difficulty (other than my newness to Ruby).  I explained why I used it in the appended post edit.  It seems like a flat hash (or perhaps even regular arrays) would've been better.

Comment: I spoke with Max yesterday. We both appreciate the techniques suggested here. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

So first of all, the structure

```
arr1 = [
    {0=>"pmet-add-install-module-timings.patch"},
    {1=>"pmet-change-sample-data-load-order.patch"},
    {2=>"pmet-configurable-recurring.patch"},
    {3=>"pmet-consumers-run-staggered-by-sleep.patch"},
    # etc
]
```

is a little odd. It's easier to work with as a flat hash, e.g.

```
h1 = {
    0 => "pmet-add-install-module-timings.patch",
    1 => "pmet-change-sample-data-load-order.patch",
    2 => "pmet-configurable-recurring.patch",
    3 =>"pmet-consumers-run-staggered-by-sleep.patch",
    # etc
}
```

Fortunately it's quite easy to transform between the two:

```
h1 = arr1.reduce(&:merge)
h2 = arr2.reduce(&:merge)
```

From this point, [Enumerable methods](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html) (in this case, the ever-useful [map](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-map), [group_by](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by), and [transform_values](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-transform_values)) will take you the rest of the way:

```
indexed_by_val = h2.
  group_by { |k,v| v }.
  transform_values { |vals| vals.map(&:first) }
```

Which gives you a map of val to indexes:

```
{
  "magento2-base"=>[0, 8, 13],
  "magento/module-sample-data"=>[1],
  "magento/module-configurable-sample-data"=>[2],
  # etc
}
```

and then we can replace those lists of indexes with the corresponding values in h1:

```
result = indexed_by_val.transform_values do |indexes|
  indexes.map do |idx|
    { idx => h1[idx] }
  end
end
```

which produces your desired data structure:

```
{
  "magento2-base"=>[
    {0=>"pmet-add-install-module-timings.patch"},
    {8=>"pmet-fix-module-loader-algorithm.patch"},
    {13=>"pmet-stop-catching-sample-data-errrors-during-install.patch"}
  ],
  "magento/module-sample-data"=>[
    {1=>"pmet-change-sample-data-load-order.patch"}
  ],
  "magento/module-configurable-sample-data"=>[
    {2=>"pmet-configurable-recurring.patch"}
  ],
  # etc
}
```

I did notice that in your expected output that you specified, the values are hashes *or* arrays. I would recommend against this practice. It's much better to have a uniform data type for all a hash's keys and values. But, if you really did want to do this for whatever reason, it's not too difficult:

```
# I am not advising this approach
result2 = result.transform_values do |arr|
  arr.length > 1 ? arr : arr[0]
end
```

By the way, I know this kind of functional programming / enumerable chaining code can be a bit hard to decipher. so I would recommend running it line-by-line for your understanding.

---

Assuming you're using the unified data structure I mentioned above, I would recommend calling `.transform_values { |vals| vals.reduce(&:merge) }` on your final result so that the values are single hashes instead of multiple hashes:

```
{
  "magento2-base"=>{
    0=>"pmet-add-install-module-timings.patch",
    8=>"pmet-fix-module-loader-algorithm.patch",
    13=>"pmet-stop-catching-sample-data-errrors-during-install.patch"
  },
  "magento/module-sample-data"=>{
    1=>"pmet-change-sample-data-load-order.patch"
  ],
  "magento/module-configurable-sample-data"=>{
    2=>"pmet-configurable-recurring.patch"
  },
  # etc
}
```

Comment: Max, thanks so much for this. I’ll read over it in more detail to really dig in but I wanted to respond to your point about the unified data structure. It’s something that I had also considered – that is, using an array of hashes even if there’s only one value in the array. Ultimately, the resultant hash will be converted to json. If the json structure gives me what I need using the uniform structure, I’m all for it. Again, thanks for spending time on this.

Comment: @SteveK If you're going to convert it to JSON I'd say it's even more important to use unified data structures. For example Javascript doesn't let you check if it's an array or hash in the same way that ruby does (there is no `.class` method). So how would your code know?

Comment: Understood, thank you! For more background on the overall challenge and how I ended up here, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60789974/125965. I managed to get close (except for the duplicate key issue between ruby and json which this question attempts to solve). to_json seems to work well from what I’ve seen. Hoping that stays true in this case, too.

Comment: @SteveK yes, to_json and JSON.parse will all work fine, the issue is in terms of writing code to traverse through the data structure

Comment: Max, a question regarding the data structure: given that both you and @Jörg W Mittag have commented on its oddity and JWM points that that both arrays could, in fact, just be arrays, would it be better for me to simplify it as such?  (Both arrays of hashes come from the same source after all). If so, how would the enumerable method suggestions change?  I've tried them on two arrays rather than the flattened hashes and I see that there are errors, so I assume the methods rely on flattened hashes?

Comment: @SteveK as a hash, iterating will yield <idx,val> to the block. As an array, if you add `.with_index` then iterating will yield <val,idx>. So it's basically the same thing but the tuples have reversed order. You could use `indexed_by_val = arr2.group_by.with_index { |val, idx| val }.transform_values { |tuples| tuples.map { |tuple| tuple[1] } }`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210122/discussion-between-steve-k-and-max-pleaner).